# hide previous map marker in angular2

Tags: marker

This code adds marker on a clicked position but wont hide the previous marker.Can anyone help me.

```
    let c = L.marker([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], {
      icon: L.icon({
        iconSize: [25, 41],
        iconAnchor: [13, 41],

        iconUrl: 'assets/download2.png',


      })
```

Comment: Do you happen to use Leaflet?

Comment: yes. @Lasjos Arpad

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you have a map and you click somewhere, where a marker appears correctly, but on every click, the previous marker should disappear if exists. Am I correct?

Comment: yes u got it right

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `map` is a variable and `c` is the marker and you can reach both, this will remove the marker from the map:

```
map.removeLayer(c);
```

If you have trouble using this answer to your benefit, then you will need to give more information about your code.